# Will this result in a crash.. ? or can we send a message to nil in Swift as well..?

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to get my head around Swift and have a doubt.

```
if let cn = respObj["cabNumber"].string where !cn.isEmpty {
   booking.cabNumber = cn
}
```

I understand this would check for the string being nil or not but 
what will happen in this case if the response object doesnot have the cabNumber key and object pair in it. We are using SwiftyJSON.

Comment: You are conditionally unwrapping the optional `if let...` so if that key isn't present then the clause inside the if statement won't execute.

Comment: Note that where part will be executed only if the let part succeeds. So in your case the code won't crash and if cn is non existent, it will not evaluate the where part in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It must be:

```
if let cn = respObj["cabNumber"] as? String where !cn.isEmpty {
      booking.cabNumber = cn
}
```

In there, the expression `let cn = respObj["cabNumber"] as? String` will check whether the key `cabNumber` exists in the Dictionary. The second expression `where ! cn.isEmpty` checks whether the value is an empty string.

Note, that if `cabNumber` key exists but has a JSON null value, it will return an instance of `NSNull` instead of nil.

Comment: There is no such `NSNull` in SwiftyJSON.

Comment: `.string` was valid, it's one of SwiftyJSON's "optional getters".

Answer (score 1):

### It does not crash. Your code is correct.

Infact you are conditional unwrapping the value inside the key

```
respObj["cabNumber"].string
```

- The `where` is executed only if `respObj["cabNumber"].string` is a valid `String`.
- `booking.cabNumber = cn` is executed only if `respObj["cabNumber"].string` is a valid non empty `String`

More specifically:

```
if let cn = respObj["cabNumber"].string 
   where !cn.isEmpty { // executed only if cn is a a valid String
   booking.cabNumber = cn // executed only if cn is a valid non empty String
}
```